# Custom Font Size Highchart Word Cloud

Tags: reactjs, highcharts

I came across an  [official highcharts article](https://www.highcharts.com/docs/chart-and-series-types/word-cloud-series#custom-placement-strategies) defining the method for **custom font size** for wordclouds.

Can anyone help on how to implement this **deriveFont** functionality in react highcharts to adjust the wordcloud font-size?

```
import React from 'react';
import Highcharts from 'highcharts';
import HighchartsReact from 'highcharts-react-official';

require('highcharts/modules/wordcloud.js')(Highcharts);



    const Word = (props) => {

            const options = {
                series: [{
                    colors: ['#28B463', '#27AE60', '#186A3B', '#ABEBC6', '#73C6B6'],
                    type: 'wordcloud',             
                    data: props.positcloud, //passing the data from props
                    name: 'Count'
                }],
                title: {
                    text: ''
                },
                chart: {

                    height: 330,
                    margin: 15,
                    type: 'line'
                  },

            };

            return (
                <div>
                    {/* React wrapper for Highcharts */}
                    <HighchartsReact 
                    highcharts={Highcharts} 
                    constructorType={'chart'}
                    options={options} />
                </div>
            )
    }

    export default Word;
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The way to define custom font sizing for `wordcloud` series in React is the same as in the article. You need to overwrite `deriveFontSize` method in `wordcloud` prototype:

```
import Highcharts from "highcharts";
import wordCloud from "highcharts/modules/wordcloud.js";
import HighchartsReact from "highcharts-react-official";

wordCloud(Highcharts);

Highcharts.seriesTypes.wordcloud.prototype.deriveFontSize = function (relativeWeight) {
    var maxFontSize = 25;
    // Will return a fontSize between 0px and 25px.
    return Math.floor(maxFontSize * relativeWeight); 
};
```

**Live demo:** https://codesandbox.io/s/highcharts-react-demo-yz3t3

Comment: Can you please tell me from my snippet on how to add the solution you suggested, as my data is coming from props/REST API already in a format [word, weight] from some component

Comment: Hi @bubble-cord, Do you mean something like this: https://codesandbox.io/s/highcharts-react-demo-hxfu3 ? If not, please adapt the online example to demonstrate your problem.